# SMTP Authentication Support + Unable to send e-mail

Tags: emails, users

I'm working on my localhost with a drupal project. I'd like to be able to send emails so I installed the SMTP Authentication Support module. Now I'm configuring it to send it with my gmail address but the test mail can't be send. I always get this error:

```
Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.
```

My Settings:

**SMTP Server**: smtp.gmail.com
**SMTP Port**: 465
**Use encrypted protocol**: no
**Username**: myusername@gmail.com (yes, this is correct in my settings)
**Password**: mypassword (yes, this is correct in my settings)
**E-mail from address**: myusername@gmail.com
**E-mail from name**: my username
**E-mail address to send a test e-mail to**: myotheremailaddress@hotmail.com

When I check the Enable Debugging checkbox I get this after trying:

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 
SMTP -> ERROR: EHLO not accepted from server: 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 
SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server: 
SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server: 
SMTP -> NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connectedSMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I've also tried it with PHPMailer module with the same settings, same result ..

Comment: I'd recommend to use [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) library...

Comment: @xurshid29: That doesn't really help the user answer their question.

Comment: @rooby I know this doesn't help him,.. this is just a suggestion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Gmail needs SSL encryption, so I had to select that in the list of encryption, my bad!